# AWS ENI doesn't get public IP adress even tough its subnet is set to assign

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, aws-cdk, amazon-vpc, elastic-network-interface

I have created a VPC and an Elastic Network Interface, but my ENI doesn't get assigned a public IP adress. I checked the subnet that the ENI is in, and it has its `Auto-assign public IPv4 address` option is set to `yes`. I even re-created the ENI and it still doesn't get assigned public IP.

I used AWS CDK to create these resources. Here are the code snippets that I used when creating these resources

```
    const vpc = new Vpc(this, "common:ec2.Vpc", {
      vpcName: "common",
      natGateways: 0,
    });
```

```
    const msiEni = new CfnNetworkInterface(
      this,
      `msi-${COMMON_INSTANCE_NAME}:ec2.CfnNetworkInterface`,
      {
        subnetId: instance.instance.subnetId!,
        groupSet: [sg.securityGroupId],
      }
    );
```

Comment: Is it a private subnet?

Comment: No, its public, There is even an ec2 instance in the same subnet with public ip auto assigned

Comment: The short answer is that ENIs don't have public IP addresses. You can associate an elastic IP to an ENI (with limitations), and EC2 (plus other services) can associate an IP from a shared pool. _What is the actual problem that you're trying to solve?_

Comment: Im remote ssh forwarding to my personal computers from an ec2 instance. To access different computers without assigning them individual ports, i decided to create multiple network interfaces for each pc, and assign their ip adress to a dns record. So i can access to my pcs from different domain names and not override ports for the services that i want to access

Comment: For e.g. i have 2 pcs running nginx, if i have 3 eni on ec2, my pcs can access to ec2 on original eni and allocare/remote forward port 80s on the other network interfaces. And if I create an A record for each public ip of enis, i can access to my pcs with pc1.mydomain.com and pc2.mydomain.com

Comment: I'm not entirely sure of what you want to do, but it sounds like you want a bastion host with multiple public IP addresses. In which case, I don't believe that you can have more than one IP address for an EC2 instance (but don't have a doc link). I really sounds like you want to run a VPN, and access your in-VPC servers directory. The AWS Client VPN is an easy solution, but you can also install OpenVPN on any instance and just pay instance charges (much like a bastion).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The auto-assign public IP address attribute on VPC subnets only applies to the primary ENI attached to each EC2 instance (interface eth0) on the subnet, and the IP is only attached while the instance is actually running.  It doesn't apply to any other ENIs on the subnet.

The only way to associate multiple public IP addresses with a single EC2 instance is by using Elastic IP addresses (EIP), which can be attached to individual ENIs or can be bound directly to one specific private IP of an ENI where the ENI has secondary private IPs.

An hourly charge applies for each EIP attached to an EC2 instance, whether the instance is running or stopped, except for the first EIP, which is not billed as long as the instance is running.  EIPs also incur charges when allocated but not attached to any ENI, to discourage inefficient use.